# Use Barcode (code128.ttf) in Freemarker via odt template

Tags: java, pdf, freemarker, odt, xdocreport

I'm trying generate PDF file via Freemarker with odt template.
I added font code128.ttf in my OS (Windows 7)
I created ODT template in Microsoft Office Word 2010.
In this template i created field: ${MyBarcode.stringForBarcode}, 
and applied font code128.ttf for this field via tools of Word.
Next I saved template as *.ODT file.

Then I tried use transform:

```
Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF).via(ConverterTypeVia.ODFDOM);
IXDocReport report = getReport(uniqueTemplateId, templateContent);
report.convert(contextMap, options, outPdfFile);
```

But when I opened result file (PDF) there field was empty.
I think font didn't transfer in converting moment.

Maybe do you know how generate PDF with Barcode via Freemarker and ODT template ?

Comment: were you able to find a fix for same ?